# tempdb usage at Azure SQLDW

Tags: azure-synapse, tempdb, sql-data-warehouse

Can I track or get a report every 30 minutes to sum the tempdb usage by user id for AZureSQlDW?

Any suggestions are highly appreciated

Thanks,
Cherishma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-manage-monitor?#monitoring-tempdb-with-views) has a query that will return the info you need. It primarily uses the `sys.dm_pdw_nodes_db_session_space_usage` DMV. You could run that query and insert it to a table or `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE AS SELECT` to export to files on some regular basis for later monitoring.